# Port of localhost keeps changing during Eclipse debugging

Tags: java, eclipse, debugging, localhost

Whenever I set a breakpoint in eclipse (java), and resume it, it gives an error in the debug window:

```
<disconnected> MyProgram at localhost:20878
```

The number after "localhost" is random and changes each time I debug. This is really preventing me from making my projects.
I searched the web a lot and couldn't find an answer for my problem.

Comment: Are you trying to use the remote debugger? Don't do that if you don't have to. How do you start your program for debugging?

Comment: Could you please post the error trace.Which server you are using ?.Ideally the project source added to the server for debugging and the skip debugging option should not be enabled.

Comment: Well, I just click on the debug button (F11). I never configured anything for the debugging.

Comment: I'm kinda new to eclipse. I just downloaded it and began learning java programming. I just set a breakpoint and click on the debug button. After I click on the resume, it shows the error I mentioned in the debug window and doesn't let me resume again or see the values of the variables. The resume button etc become grey and can't be clicked anymore. I never configured it to use the so-called remote debugger. I just click on the debug button.